# nodejs - Downloading a file from another host and streaming that file to another client the same time

Tags: node.js

I have a storage host and a server, my client will request file from server but the files are from storage host. Anyway to make the server transferring the file from storage host to client but the client still see that file coming from the server?

I kind of want to hide where the storage host is. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [nodejs stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) to tranfert your file from the Storage to the client via the server.

Example :

> |Client| -- ask file --> |Server| -- ask file --> |Storage|
>
> |Storage| -- return stream --> |Server| -- return stream --> |Client|

The storage returns a stream as the response and the server pipes this stream to the client response. Your server has only a proxy role.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at nodejs stream. But do you have any sample codes?

Comment: This previous [stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145738/stream-response-into-http-response) shows how to stream to a http response. Also this [medium article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93) is great to understand how stream works.